# "Removing a connection that never existed!" in logcat during uploading file in dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am new to use dropbox firstly i am trying to upload the file from android phone into dropbox using android studio.Firstly i authenticate it.During Debugging i get it is correct means authenticated and then i upload file i also create app in android. But after all processing it shows "Removing a connection that never existed!" in logcat window and file does not uploaded i dont know what is the problem can anyone help me.Appreciate in advance.
Code: I use following code

enter code here

manifestFile

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
            <data android:scheme="db-v4n6dxu3uufev8w" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="Dropbox Sync" />
</application>
```

MainActivity

DropboxAPI mDBApi;
    static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxx";

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
    Upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Upload);
    Upload.setOnClickListener(this);
    loggedIn(false);
    AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(DROPBOX_APP_KEY, DROPBOX_APP_SECRET);
    //  session.setOAuth2AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
    SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences(DROP_BOX_NAME, 0);
    String key = sh.getString(DROPBOX_APP_KEY, null);
    String secret = sh.getString(DROPBOX_APP_SECRET, null);
    if (key != null && secret != null) {
        AccessTokenPair pair = new AccessTokenPair(key, secret);
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys, access, pair);
    } else {
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys, access);
    }
    mDBApi = new DropboxAPI(session);
    session.setOAuth2AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
    //    session.finishAuthentication();

}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    AndroidAuthSession session = (AndroidAuthSession) mDBApi.getSession();
    if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {

        try {
            mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();
            TokenPair token = session.getAccessTokenPair();
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(DROP_BOX_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString(DROPBOX_APP_KEY, token.key);
            edit.putString(DROPBOX_APP_SECRET, token.secret);
            edit.commit();
            loggedIn(true);
            Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Authenticating OK!");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("DbAuthLog", "No authenticating");
    }
}


public void onClick(View v) {


    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.login:

            if (userlogin) {

                mDBApi.getSession().unlink();

                loggedIn(false);

            } else {

                ((AndroidAuthSession) mDBApi.getSession()).startAuthentication(MainActivity.this);


            }

            break;

        case R.id.Upload:

            UploasdFile uploadFile = new UploasdFile(mDBApi, DROP_BOX_FILE_DIR, this);

            uploadFile.execute();

            break;

        default:

            break;

    }

}

public void loggedIn(boolean isLogged) {
    userlogin = isLogged;
    Upload.setEnabled(isLogged);
    login.setText(isLogged ? "Log out" : "Log in");
}
```

Upload File

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {

        try {


            File newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TestFolder");
            if (!newFolder.exists()) {
                newFolder.mkdir();
            }
            File file = new File(newFolder, "MyTest" + ".txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter write = null;

            write = new FileWriter(file);
            write.append("This is some random text I write to test this application");
            write.flush();
            write.close();
            System.out.println("File =" + file);
            System.out.println("mpath =" + mPath);
            System.out.println("gfUploads.length()v" + file.length());
            if (newFolder.exists()) {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                DropboxAPI.Entry newEntry = mApi.putFileOverwrite("MyTest.txt", fis, file.length(), null);
                System.out.println("eupload2");
            } else {

                System.out.println(" nottt okk");
            }
            return true;

        } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
            // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
            mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";

            System.out.println("error= "+ e);


        } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
            // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
            mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
            System.out.println("error1= "+ e);
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // Unknown error
            mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
            System.out.println("error2= "+ e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("error3= " + e);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("error4= " + e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Output in Logcat Window

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikZGA.png)

Comment: It certainly looks like the upload is succeeding. Can you tell us why you believe the upload failed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem by “Removing a connection that never existed! in logcat during uploading file on dropbox" or  "Not Uploading File on dropbox from android studio". There are many reasons behind this problem like there may be no space to store our data on dropbox,we are not able to authenticate with Dropbox etc.But in my case there is authentication problem Actually to upload the file the user by whom we share the dropbox app must have the account in dropbox and must have the permission to access our app.

Thanks